# Change PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Hi I have built an array and in the final process of finishing the script.

I have been building a web crawler which scans specific links on sites specified. The crawler stores all the links in one page and then inserts them into another array (news_stories) with the links specified in them.

Now the way the new array is structured is like this.

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [title] =>  The Qlick 
        [description] => Qlick
        [keywords] => Search Engine, Web, Sexy, Noah Smith
        [link] => http://www.theqlick.com/qlickdates.php
    )
  )
```

And that is difficult for me to implode and insert into a mysql table. Now my code below uses functions to grab titles, descriptions etc for each link it finds and then inserts them into the new array if they match.

Is there anyway to get this to delete the Array() at the top of the array and just have the array which specifies the title, description etc. 
I want the output to look like:

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [title] =>  The Qlick 
        [description] => Qlick
        [keywords] => Search Engine, Web, Sexy, Noah Smith
        [link] => http://www.theqlick.com/qlickdates.php
    )
```

Any ideas?

```
  $bbc_values = array('http://www.theqlick.com/festivalfreaks.php', 'http://www.theqlick.com/qlickdates.php');

  $news_stories = array();
  foreach ($links as $link) {
      $item = array(
        "title"       => Titles($link), 
        "description" => getMetas($link),
        "keywords" => getKeywords($link), 
        "link"        => $link                 
       );

      if (empty($item["description"])) {
          $item["description"] = getWord($link);
      }


      foreach($bbc_values as $bbc_value) {
          // note the '===' . this is important
          if(strpos($item['link'], $bbc_value) === 0) {
              $news_stories[] = $item;
          }
      }
   }

   $data = '"' . implode('" , "', $news_stories) . '"';
   $query = 
   //CNN algorithm
   print_r($news_stories);
```

Comment: why not remove the first $news_stories array? When you open with it, it's an empty array. Then you're just adding to the array with $news_stories[]. Just doing $news_stories[] will create the array for you

Comment: have done @MrTechie and nothing seems to have changed

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to flatten the array to a single dimension? What would your output look like?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski editted code.

Comment: @MatthewSmith That's what I thought, but you are appending to `$news_stories` in a loop, which implies that you expect more than one of them.  And that means it doesn't make sense to remove that outer dimension.  (which is easily done by `$inner = array_pop($news_stories);`  Why are you imploding these values? It looks like you might be building up a `VALUES ()` list for an `INSERT` statement, in which case you really ought to be using an API which supports prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

PHP *foreach()* is an iterator, intended to let your programming perform the same action on a collection of data.  In the existing design, the *$news_stories* array can contain multiple individual "sub-arrays", with each such "sub-array" being the unit of data you want to insert into your data base.

When you get down to the part about creating queries, you can use something like this:

```
foreach ($news_stories as $story)
{
    /* CREATE AND RUN QUERY USING DATA IN $story */
}
```

You can use *var_dump()* to look at the contents of a *$story* array.  When you do that, it will probably make sense instantly.  PHP *foreach()* does not care if you have one element or a hundred elements.  If you have zero elements, it will not run the code inside the control structure.